# Group By function failing to show result

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I want to produce a table with patients under 18 years received a certain amount of vaccines in clinic number 6. The age and clinic conditions worked fine at first, but adding the total number of vaccines turned out to be problematic. Screenshots of tables and their columns are included for clarification[image]. Working with SQL Oracle (apex). All tables are shown at the bottom (middle)

```
  SELECT p.PATIENT_NO, 
         p.PATIENT_FN, 
         p.PATIENT_LN, 
         p.PATIENT_DOB, 
         a.appointment_no, 
         count(vaccine_no)
    FROM PATIENTS p, 
         appointment_register r, 
         appointments a
   WHERE CLINIC_NO = 6 
     AND ADD_MONTHS(PATIENT_DOB, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE 
GROUP BY p.patient_no
  HAVING a.appointment_no = r.appointment_no
```

Comment: It seems you haven't *JOIN* the tables: `PATIENTS, appointment_register, appointments`

Comment: where and how would you put the JOIN statements?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: As it is now, the tables are _cross joined_.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.PATIENT_NO, 
         p.PATIENT_FN, 
         p.PATIENT_LN, 
         p.PATIENT_DOB, 
         a.appointment_no, 
         count(vaccine_no)
    FROM PATIENTS p, 
         appointment_register r, 
         appointments a
   WHERE CLINIC_NO = 6 
     AND ADD_MONTHS(PATIENT_DOB, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE
     and a.appointment_no = r.appointment_no 
     and p.PATIENT_NO=a.PATIENT_NO
GROUP BY p.patient_no,p.PATIENT_FN, 
         p.PATIENT_LN, 
         p.PATIENT_DOB, 
         a.appointment_no
```

Comment: No join condition for the PATIENTS table needed?

Comment: i adding and p.PATIENT_NO=a.PATIENT_NO to where clause

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor, start using explicit `JOIN` syntax. When you do, silly mistakes like this wont happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try going small step after small step: can you query `Patients`, `Appointments` and `Appointment_Register` (you have to `JOIN` them)?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Patients p JOIN
         Appointments a ON (p.Patient_No = a.Patient_No) JOIN
         Appointment_Register r ON (r.Appointment_No = a.Appointment_No AND
                                    r.Patient_No = p.Patient_No)
```

Add `WHERE` and have the query with `Patients` filtered. Then, let's count vaccines per patient:

```
  SELECT p.Patient_No,
         Count(1)      -- All vaccines
    FROM Patients p JOIN
         Appointments a ON (p.Patient_No = a.Patient_No) JOIN
         Appointment_Register r ON (r.Appointment_No = a.Appointment_No AND 
                                    r.Patient_No = p.Patient_No)
   WHERE p.Clinic_No = 6 
     AND ADD_MONTHS(p.Patient_Dob, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE -- 29.02.2000 + 18 years = ?
GROUP BY p.Patient_No
```

Finally, for certain amount of Aggegated vaccine add `HAVING`

```
  SELECT p.Patient_No 
    FROM Patients p JOIN
         Appointments a ON (p.Patient_No = a.Patient_No) JOIN
         Appointment_Register r ON (r.Appointment_No = a.Appointment_No AND 
                                    r.Patient_No = p.Patient_No)
   WHERE p.Clinic_No = 6 
     AND ADD_MONTHS(p.Patient_Dob, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE 
GROUP BY p.Patient_No
  HAVING Count(1) > 3 -- or what ever
```

we have `Patient` ids; if it's not enough let's add `WITH`

```
WITH MyIds AS (
  SELECT p.Patient_No AS Patient_No
    FROM Patients p JOIN
         Appointments a ON (p.Patient_No = a.Patient_No) JOIN
         Appointment_Register r ON (r.Appointment_No = a.Appointment_No AND
                                    r.Patient_No = p.Patient_No)
   WHERE p.Clinic_No = 6 
     AND ADD_MONTHS(p.Patient_Dob, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE 
GROUP BY p.Patient_No
  HAVING Count(1) > 3
)  

SELECT p.*
  FROM Patients p JOIN MyIds ON (p.Patient_No = MyIds.Patient_No)
```

Comment: `JOIN` syntax doesn't require any brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The Vaccination table is not part of your join. Please add it to the join

```
 SELECT p.PATIENT_NO, 
     p.PATIENT_FN, 
     p.PATIENT_LN, 
     p.PATIENT_DOB, 
     a.appointment_no, 
     count(v.vaccine_no)
FROM PATIENTS p, 
     appointment_register r, 
     appointments a,
     vaccine v
WHERE CLINIC_NO = 6 
AND ADD_MONTHS(PATIENT_DOB, 18 * 12) > SYSDATE 
GROUP BY p.patient_no
HAVING a.appointment_no = r.appointment_no
```

Comment: No join conditions needed?

Comment: comma notation will work as well.Let me know if i the understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Syntax-wise it's fine, but you'll return a cartesian product.

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor, start using explicit `JOIN` syntax. When you do, silly mistakes like this wont happen.